# F#: Seq.forall weirdness?

Tags: f#, seq

Given `let ra = ResizeArray<int> ()`:

```
Seq.forall (fun i ->
                    let q = i % 2
                    if 0 = q then ra.Add i
                    true ) <| seq { 1..10 }
```

If I do that, `ra.Count` returns `5`.

```
Seq.forall (fun i ->
                    let q = i % 2
                    if 0 = q then ra.Add i
                    0 = q ) <| seq { 1..10 }
```

If I do that, `ra.Count` returns `0`.

So, what, unless every iteration of the lambda function evaluates to true, then effectively none of the code in the function is executed, or what??

What's going on, here?

Comment: Quoting the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370522.aspx): "*If any application returns `false` then the overall result is `false` and no further elements are tested.*"

Comment: forall + side effects is a bad combo.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Depends on the situation.  In this case (i.e. briefly demonstrating functionality), it was eminently practical.

Comment: use Seq.iter. seq { 1..10 } |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x % 2 = 0) |> Seq.iter (fun x -> ra.Add x) or seq { 1..10 } |> Seq.iter (fun x -> if x % 2 = 0 then ra.Add x)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use a value of "false" to cease the `Seq.forall` function from processing further elements.

Since `1 % 2 = 0` is false, this stops the evaluation on the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks, didn't catch that in the docs.  I need the list to be fully iterated over, guess I'll have to use Seq.map then Seq.forall ?

Comment: @MiloDC - Have you considered `Seq.iter`?

Comment: @JoelMueller Yes, but Seq.iter returns unit; I need to know whether any of the lambda functions evaluated to false.  Seq.map |> Seq.forall is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach would be more functional:

```
let (anyOdds, evens) =
    seq {1..10}
    |> Seq.fold (fun (anyOdds, xs) x ->
        if x % 2 = 0 then
            anyOdds, x :: xs
        else true, xs) (false, [])
```

Feel comfortable to ditch ResizeArray's in favor of F# lists they are generally efficient unless you have specific requirements.

Comment: Guys, my example was typed up real fast, just to demonstrate functionality.  I'm not actually implementing a function that looks for even numbers. :) (My actual function is radically different and totally unrelated in purpose.)

Comment: I understand, but it doesn't mean you can't do it in a functional way without side-effecting.

Comment: Sure, I simply wasn't interested in anal-retentively tailoring my example (which makes sense in the context of my actual program) to eliminate side effects.